# Bot Framework Composer AdaptiveCard validation

Tags: botframework

I'm not able to validate AdaptiveCard input.text field. The aim of this validation is to check i.e. if field is blank etc. If blank repeat adaptivecard. Is it possible. I've tried to do it for 1 day and everything failed.

AdaptiveCard code

````
    # adaptivecardjson_NewCard()
- ```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "${NewCard()}",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "CityID",
            "placeholder": "City name"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "StreetID",
            "placeholder": "Street name"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Number",
            "id" : "PropertyID",
            "placeholder" : "Property number"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "ZipID",
            "placeholder": "Zip code"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Submit"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2"
}
```
````

I added a bunch of validation code but none of them works. When user put value it still saying that there is no value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl8Na.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OllWP.png

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you could do the validation on the Adaptive Card side if you wanted to:

```
{
   "type": "Input.Text",
   "id": "CityID",
   "placeholder": "City name",
   "isRequired": true,
   "errorMessage": "Please enter city name"
},
```

But it can be done on the bot side too, depending on the needs/specifics. Is your prompt a *prompt for text*? If so, it will always be invalid because the submitted prompt coming back has no `text` value and therefore will be invalid to a prompt for text.